# Can someone shed light on this python statement pls: return {"%s__within" % field_name: poly}?

Tags: python, django, geodjango

The entire function:

```
def build_bbox_filter(srs, bbox_val, field_name):
  poly = poly_from_bbox(bbox_val) 
  poly.set_srid(srs.srid)
  return {"%s__within" % field_name: poly}
```

Comment: What about the expression? You have a key, formed by `"%s__within" % field_name`, and a value, `poly`, put together into a dictionary.

Answer (score 2):

You might find it easier to understand if you split the final line into two:

```
key = "%s__within" % field_name
return {key: poly}
```

So, for example, if `field_name` was `'my_field'`, then the function would return the dictionary:

```
{'my_field__within': <poly>}
```

Comment: Cheers, I understand now.

Answer (score 0):

The function returns a dictionary with a single key that's created via string substitution. The key will be `"[value_of_field_name]__witihin"` and the value will be the value of `poly` whatever that is. Example:

```
def return_dictionary(field_name, poly):

    return {"%s__within" % field_name: poly}

return_dictionary("name_of_my_field", "value_of_poly")
```

Output:

```
>>> def return_dictionary(field_name, poly):
...     return {"%s__within" % field_name: poly}
... 
>>> return_dictionary("name_of_my_field", "value_of_poly")
{'name_of_my_field__within': 'value_of_poly'}
>>>
```